# Is this asking for a POS equation or SOP?

Tags: digital-logic, sop

So here's the question:

***We want to design a circuit that determines if a four-bit number is less than 10 and is also even.***

***a. (10 points) Write an expression of M such that M=1 if the four-bit number X (x3 x2 x1 x0) is less than 10
and is also even.***

Is this asking for the answer in POS form since it is using "M" instead of "m"?

Comment: Why do you think they care? Besides, comparator should in fact perform an arithmetical operation, thrn you can use its output together with the bit that depends on oddness.

Answer (score 2):

They probably want the simplest form.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The conventional representation for the POS form is M(.). Now, since the last bit for the even numbers is 0, it is enough to have 3 bits will all numbers from 0 to 4. So, we just need a mod 5 counter to generate all these numbers and the last bit of the four bits (LSB) being grounded always.

Comment: Can you give some citation or reference for your statement that "POS form is M(.)"? I've been doing this for a long time and never saw this as a "conventional representation". In my experience we add words to the question to make it clear what is expected.